# HTML5 Links in navbar are displayed wrong

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem where the links are not shown in a row but instead some of them are stacked underneath eachother. Are there any step by step tips out here on how I can solve it and also an explanation to why my links in the navbar shows up messed up?? I only wanna use CSS and HTML, no JS.

**Please take note:** I have a picture of how i want the header to look and also a print screeen of how it looks in GChrome right now. However i am not familiar with posting questions here on StackOverflow so i dont know how to post 2 images in the same question. So please dont be too hardjudging since I am a beginner.

```css
header {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.logo img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

.header li {
  float:left;
  font-family: 'Brother 1816';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #000;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav a{
 width: 400px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #a71b1a;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
      <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="logo/logo_250x150.png" alt="Freyas logotype."></a>
      </div>

      <nav class="navigation"> 
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li> 
            <li><a href="about_me.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

How it should look

[image]

How it looks
[image]

Comment: Just paste the images. If you cannot, then link to imgur and I will paste them for you

Comment: [Have a look around stackoverflow first](https://www.google.com/search?q=horizontal+menu+css+flex+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: from what i can see using codepen the margin 150 is too much and the width 400px is too much try adjusting those to see if you get to where you want to be.

Comment: Use flexbox instead of floating, hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: @mplungjan here is the link to the image of how i want it to look like: https://imgur.com/a/xH0lAc5

here is the link to the image showing how it is currently dispayed in my browser:https://imgur.com/UPgzme5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width property associated with your links is causing them to take up 400px each which then wraps down the page

```css
nav a{
 width: 400px;
}
```

remove the width property and the links should sit on the same line.

Alternatively use flexbox https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp to space the links across the page as you desire.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Width and display: block in your a tag are causing the issue. Also add display: inline to your <li> properties to make elements render in the same row.